# Error while assigning permission in Hive and MySql

Tags: mysql, hive

Hive version - 3.1.2
SQL connector version - 8.0

Trying to grant permissions like - GRANT all on *.* to 'hiveuser'@localhost identified by 'hivepassword';

Error - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'indentified by 'hivepassword'

Please help, I am stuck here! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql 8.0 GRANT instruction doesn't support implicit account creation anymore. Therefore the "`identified by`" option is not part of the instruction anymore. (See [13.7.1.6 GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html))

So:

- If the user account you are trying to grant doesn't exist yet, you have to create it first with the `CREATE USER 'hiveuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'hivepassword';` instruction.
- Then you can grant it with your grant instruction, but without the password definition part: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'hiveuser'@'localhost';`